# Unresolved import `std::lazy` after updating rust

Tags: rust

This used to work fine, however after upgrading Rust to `rustc 1.67.0-nightly (b7bc90fea 2022-11-21)` (haven't done that in a while), it no longer works:

I've enabled `once_cell` of course.

`#![feature(once_cell)]`

`use std::lazy::Lazy;`

Produces error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `std::lazy`
39 | use std::lazy::Lazy;
   |          ^^^^ could not find `lazy` in `std`
```

I've searched through GitHub issues on rustlang and nobody seems to have the same problem.

I've checked the latest docs and nothing changed in terms of location.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/lazy/index.html

If lazy is in std, but the compiler can't find it, what do I need to do in such a situation? Is a reinstall necessary?

Comment: You should be looking at the `nightly` docs, where you'll see that they've been moved to [`std::cell::LazyCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/cell/struct.LazyCell.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've checked the wrong place. Nightly docs are in:

https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/

...which shows this module indeed does not exist anymore, as it was moved to `std::cell` for `Lazy` (which is now named [`LazyCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/cell/struct.LazyCell.html)) and `std::sync` for `SyncLazy` (which is now named [`LazyLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/struct.LazyLock.html)).

This happened in [PR #98165 - once cell renamings](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/98165).